# Hourly erroneous data retrieved from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve the "average transactions per hour for 2015" from SQL Server and I'm using the following query for it:

```
select 
    avg(Cast(a.Orders as float)) as AvgOrders, a.Hour
from 
    (select 
         count(*) as Orders, 
         datepart(hour,created) as Hour,
         datepart(day,created) as Day
    from 
        ORDERS
    where 
        --      datepart(month,created) = 1
        datepart(year,created) = 2015
        and DATENAME(dw, created) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
        and branchno in ('113', '120', '122')
        and (filing = 1 or delivery = 1)
    group by 
        datepart(hour, created),
        datepart(day, created)
    ) a
group by 
    a.Hour
order by 
    a.Hour
```

This query gives me hourly data which seems to be incorrect (about 150+ transactions an hour, which I know is not correct). When I uncomment the statement `datepart(month, created) = 1` and use any month in it, then the data is close to 40 transaction an hour which is the correct data.

Why am I not able to generate correct data for the whole of 2015? Why do I get accurate data when I select monthly data?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: day 1 exists in all months, so it is grouping all months into that day. you need to group by month and year too.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, to get each hour separately, by the day it occurred on.

```
select count(*) as Orders
    , cast(created as date) as Date
    , Datepart(hour, created) as Hour  
from ORDERS
group by cast(created as date)
    , Datepart(hour, created) 
order by Date, Hour
```